# Swagger Annotations; specify two responses with same code based on optional parameter

Tags: annotations, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have a GET mapping whose path look like this /topNSolutions/{type}.And response body of this looks like {
"message": "string",
"result": {},
"status": 0
}.
Based on path variable {type}, result changes from list of Object A to list of Object B. Can we document this using swaggerAnnotations?

I tried checking for any annotations to describe the above, but didn't find any

Comment: it's nothing about swagger. it's about API design. No reason to not separate it into two API.